# My code hangs when the server returns request error

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My code is downloading the files perfectly, but it stops when the server returns a 404 error. How do I change this code to add only URLs that don't have a 404 error to the list?

```
import requests
import httplib2
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
artigos = []
pdfs = []
http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('https://www.snh2021.anpuh.org/site/anais')
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        artigos.append(link['href'])
for x in artigos:
    if x.endswith('pdf'):
        pdfs.append(x)
        print(pdfs)

def baixa_arquivo(url, endereco):
    resposta = requests.get(url)
    if resposta.status_code == requests.codes.OK:
        with open(endereco, 'wb') as novo_arquivo:
            novo_arquivo.write(resposta.content)
            print('Download concluído. Salvo em {}'.format(endereco))
    else:
        resposta.raise_for_status()
if __name__ == '__main__':
        url_basica = 'https://www.snh2021.anpuh.org/{}'
        output = 'Download'
        for i in range(1, len(pdfs)):
            nome_do_arquivo = os.path.join(output, 'artigo{}.pdf'.format(i))
            a = pdfs[i]
            baixa_arquivo(url_basica.format(a), nome_do_arquivo)
```

Comment: Can you post your error stack trace ?

Comment: Try wrapping the code that performs the request itself in a try-catch block, and you can log the problematic URLs in the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by adding a condition at the end of the code. I requested the status_code and canceled the download if the status was 404.

```
import requests
import httplib2
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

artigos = []
pdfs = []
http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('https://www.snh2021.anpuh.org/site/anais')
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        artigos.append(link['href'])
for x in artigos:
    if x.endswith('pdf'):
        pdfs.append(x)
    print(pdfs)


def baixa_arquivo(url, endereco):
    resposta = requests.get(url)
    if resposta.status_code == requests.codes.OK:
        with open(endereco, 'wb') as novo_arquivo:
            novo_arquivo.write(resposta.content)
            print('Download concluído. Salvo em {}'.format(endereco))
    else:
        resposta.raise_for_status()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_basica = 'https://www.snh2021.anpuh.org/{}'
    output = 'Download'
    for i in range(550, len(pdfs)):
        nome_do_arquivo = os.path.join(output, 'artigo{}.pdf'.format(i))
        a = pdfs[i]
        z = url_basica.format(a)
        y = requests.get(z)
        if y.status_code!=404:
            baixa_arquivo(z, nome_do_arquivo)
```